# Is there an online speech comparison programme

Tags: discussion, online-resources

I work as an Assistant Language Teacher in Japan. There is a language sample for the textbook- the school (and nearly every teacher) is super boring about using the textbook. They'd like me to sound like the CD- is there an online language comparator to tell me how close that I am sounding like the samples and advise how to get closer.

Comment: Wouldn't this question be more suited for our [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) forum?