# Where can I find a list of words in their singular and plural form?

Tags: discussion

There is a variable naming rule that I would like to enforce in my software:

> Variable names of scalar types should be written in singular form.
>
> Variable names of collection types should be written in plural form.

I'm looking for a list of english words that document spelling in both singular and plural form.
I realize there are many words whose plurality is ambiguous.
If that were notated as well, it would be a bonus.

Is there a well established source where I can find or derive this type of information?

---

Princeton has a [lexical database for English](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/), but I don't see plurality as part of their data.

Comment: Dictionaries are good places to look.

Comment: I'm sorry but questions asking for lists are off-topic here.

Comment: You might look into the answers for this question, since what you're looking for are nouns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553274/free-string-dictionary-nouns

Comment: @Centaurus Ok.  I thought it might be.  When I typed "Where can I find a list ..." many other questions appeared in this format that were not closed.  After reading the rules, I didn't see anything discouraging a user from asking for data, so I decided to post.

Comment: You could look for (a) a list of nouns and (b)lists of irregular plural forms (Wikipedia is good for the latter).

Comment: Since you're into software, you could take a look at Ruby on Rails [ActiveSupport::Inflector.pluralize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/pluralize). It does have a dictionary of irregular forms but I couldn't find the source file. Maybe the techies on StackOverflow can help you.

Comment: @Mick Perfect.  A set of regular expression rules, + a list of exceptions.  That will work better than I could have imagined.

Comment: Just occasionally, StackExchange is the best place to look. ;-)

Comment: This is unclear. Do you want a reference that an indivudual can look up individual terms as needed, or do you want a database/spreadsheet/electronic list on which to run algorithms?

Comment: I was looking for an algorithmic way to convert any word to its plural or singular form.  Initially, I thought I would need a database of all English words.  It turns out, the better approach is to have a small list of irregulars/uncountables, followed by a set of regular expressions to derive the necessary adjustments. This is what I have seen done in the ruby on rails framework, PHP doctrine, as well as MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb does this, although not perfectly.  [Their code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/utils.js) is the best starting place I can think of.

Comment: This is another good solution.  Mongodb seems to only have only plural conversions; not singular.