# Are questions on dictionaries, corpora or other linguistic tools acceptable?

Tags: discussion, support

Recently I have realized I need some advice when choosing a dictionary, a corpus or any other tool assisting in language learning. I can find lists of them on the Internet, but it would be much better to get "live" comments and notes from real users.

Are ELU and/or ELU Meta good places to ask for such recommendations?

Comment: There is a [languagelearning.se] site. Maybe they can help?

Comment: I'll take a look at it, thank you.

Comment: [This page](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/12/you-could-look-it-up/) might help, especially the two links steganographically labelled *here* and *here*.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my perspective.

I think some types of questions about resources can be on-topic. My opinion is that [it's best for resource questions to go on main](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9443/what-is-the-point-of-migrating-all-resource-requests-to-meta) but there are enough people who disagree with me to migrate a question to Meta, so that often ends up happening.

However, the type of question you describe doesn't sound to me like a very good fit for the Stack Exchange format, or for this site in general (either main or Meta).

- You say you have already found lists, but you want something other than a general list. In a way, this is good, since we already have [a list of good resources](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available). But the problem I see is that it will be difficult for you to specify what you want. People may just end up suggesting things that you've already seen on the lists you found before. This isn't very helpful. You can try to avoid it by explaining where you have looked before and which resources you don't like, but that's a bit of a pain.
- You say you want advice and " 'live' comments and notes from real users". In general, Stack Exchange is meant to have a Q&A format where there is a somewhat well-defined question, with a somewhat well-defined "best" answer for people who have that question in general. *Advice* on the other hand is best when it is personalized. There used to be a close reason called "Too Localized". It was removed, but I would say the idea still applies to some degree: people should be able to agree on what the best answer is based on factors other than the personal opinion or personal experience of the question asker.

There are probably ways to deal with both of the issues I mention. List questions are not completely off-topic network-wide, and there are a number of sites that field questions that seem advice-oriented like [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com) and [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com). However, I feel like most ELU users will resist having questions of the type you mention on the main site.

As Matt E. mentioned in the comments, you could check if Language Learning SE would consider such questions on-topic. You can also try asking in chat; there are sometimes users there who have experience with dictionaries.